# How to prevent radiotray from playing (from buffer) on lock screen after resuming

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, internet-radio

When I resume my laptop and had radiotray turned on it starts playing again (from buffer) while I'm on the lock screen. This gets really annoying when I'm somewhere it should be quiet (library, train etc.). It would also be nice to have some delay in resuming radiotray playback after unlocking the screen to be able to react to the situation I'm in.

How do I prevent that behaviour (ok, besides turning radiotray off before suspending)?

Answer (score 3):

Running 10.04, as a workaround to avoid this quite annoying behaviour, I put together the script below and saved it as **/etc/pm/sleep.d/13_radiotray**.
(In terminal: `gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/13_radiotray`, enter/paste the script code, save the file and finally make it executable with: `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/13_radiotray`.)

As you can see, what it does is: if radiotray was running on suspend/hibernate, it gets killed on resume/thaw and then restarted in "idle" mode. This works OK for me and my needs...

*(I don't know if the numbering (13...) of the script is "OK", if the final "exit $?" is necessary - or of any use at all? - but at least it works perfectly for me...)*

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/pm/sleep.d/13_radiotray

case "$1" in
  resume|thaw)
    # kill radiotray if it's running...
    if pgrep -f /usr/bin/radiotray > /dev/null ; then
      pkill -f /usr/bin/radiotray
      # ...and then restart radiotray (idle)
      # If it doesn't work with 'tty7', try '(:0.0)' or '(:0)'...
      DISPLAY=:0.0 su `who | grep 'tty7' | awk '{print $1}'` -c "radiotray > /dev/null &"
    fi
    ;;
esac

exit $?
```

Edited 2012-11-03: changed the "DISPLAY=: ..." line (see comment below) /mikwie

Comment: For me the script doesn't get radiotray back to systray. It's running when I look at the system monitor but the indicator icon isn't appearing.
Additionally there's still playback for a very short time after resuming. Don't you have the same issues?

Comment: @joschi: sorry that I haven't been able to answer/comment earlier.
No, I haven't experienced these issues on my Ubuntu 10.04 single-user system.
By the way, error messages related to radiotray or 13_radiotray should show up in /var/log/pm-suspend.

Having realised that the sed command (not mine, found it somewhere) doesn't work with all possible usernames, and that "grep (:0)" doesn't work with e.g. 12.04, I changed the script (edited the original post).
Try it - and if this still doesn't work for you, please let me know - I will do my best trying to help you.